# Anyone know what this black ribbon is in the Visual Studio 2012 breakpoint bar?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

[image: Visual studio screen shot]

Please let me know if anyone know what this is. I have no idea and am just curious.

Comment: Ok found it out, it is a bookmark for your code. FANCY!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found it out, it is a bookmark for your code. FANCY!!